# Multiple implicit model binding with one controller in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I am trying to attach multiple models with one controller using implicit model binding but I am getting the following error if I try to attach more than one model with methods.

```
index() must be an instance of App\\Http\\Models\\Modelname, string given
```

Here is my code:

```
public function index(Model1 $model1,Model2 $model2,Model3 $model3)
{
    print_r($application_endpoint);
}
```

Route:

```
Route::resource("model1.model2.model3","MyController",["except"=>["create","edit"]]);
```

Comment: Can you add also your route? Are you sure that order of parameters in route match the one in controller?

Comment: There is no issue in order of parameters and I added the route.

Answer (score 0):

Your route should looks like that:

```
Route::resource("your_route/{model1}/{model2}/{model3}","MyController",[
    "except"=>["create","edit"]
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yess you can register routes like these

```
Route::resource("model1.model2.model3","MyController",["except"=>["create","edit"]]);
```

but in your controller, you have to

```
public function index($id,$id2,$id3)
{

    print_r($application_endpoint);
}
```

OR

you can do like this

```
Route::model('key/key/key', 'MyController')
```

and in your controller

```
public function index(Model1 $model1,Model2 $model2,Model3 $model3)
{
    print_r($application_endpoint);
}
```

Comment: same I mentioned above